# Laravel 5.3: Class company does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, class, middleware, dashboard

I'm building a business directory where is going to have 2 different dashboards accordingly to the roles of the users, which can be: **Admin** or **Company**.

In order to handle this, the following procedure was developed:

*1- Create a new middleware:*

```
php artisan make:middleware Company
```

*2- Code for the Company middleware (which is the same for admin and comunity):*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Company
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            if(Auth::user()->isCompany()){
                return $next($request);     
            }
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

*3- Added the following function in my User model:*

```
public function isCompany(){
    if($this->role->Role_Type  == "Company" && $this->is_active == 1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*4- Handled the routing*

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'company'], function(){
     Route::get('/company', function(){
        return view('company.index');
    });
});
```

*5- Created a new user with the role company*

At the moment, once trying to login with that User, always get prompt with this message:

[ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class company does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmKT.png)

Any ideas in how to solve this?

To note: already tried: `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that in the code you pasted, the class name is `Community` instead of `Company`. The class name should match the name of the file, case and all. Also, can you share your middleware file? If the naming is not the issue, there may be a reference issue inside of one of your provider or kernel files.

Comment: thanks for alerting me, check now.
My apologies, problem doing copy/paste, in the code is right

Comment: can you share your kernel file as well?

Comment: since its complaining about not having a class "company", I would check to make sure all of your references to that class are capitalized correctly as well.

Comment: you're the man!!!

Didn't know that needed to add it inside of the
 
protected $routeMiddleware . It works

Comment: @tiagoperes no problem, glad you got it sorted